# When I scan NFC with my custom NFC scanner , another app is showing up , how to prevent that?

Tags: android, kotlin, sdk, adb, nfc

I've created app,that scans my hardware by NFC tags on Android,Kotlin.

when I manage to scan and scan is finished,Android system is opening another NFC app,that is system app with name Nfc Service.

Is there any possible ways to disable all other NFC apps,while I'm using my own one ?

Comment: This problem doesn't seem to be a new one on Android: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10712441/150978

Comment: I've already tried that , but it does not helped...

Comment: That answer was written vor Android 4.0 or even older versions, so it is not a big surprise  if it is no longer working.

Comment: I understand that It's not a big surprise,but I need to fix that as fast as I can so beside of searching on my own , I'am asking here , maybe someone will have an answer

Comment: Been a while since I've done this but think you need to get NfcAdapter and use enableReaderMode and disableReaderMode in your onResume/onPause methods of your activity. enable/disableForegroundDispatch shouldn't be used unless supporting android versions earlier than 4.4 I think.

Comment: You need to show your code as there are number of different way to use nfc, and some of the are old and don't work as well, you might also have used them incorrectly. Also there are a variety of NFC Tag types and data formats and without all these details it is impossible to answer